# Python: Why does Pool.map() hang when attempting to use the input arguments to its map function?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, arguments

I have the following function (shortened for readability), which I parallelize using Python's (3.5) `multiprocessing` module:

```
def evaluate_prediction(enumeration_tuple):
    i = enumeration_tuple[0]
    logits_pred = enumeration_tuple[1]
    print("This prints succesfully")
    print("This never gets printed: ")
    print(enumeration_tuple[0])
    filename = sample_names_test[i]
    onehots_pred = logits_to_onehots(logits_pred)
    np.save("/media/nfs/7_raid/ebos/models/fcn/" + channels + "/test/ndarrays/" + filename, onehots_pred)
```

However, this function hangs whenever I attempt to read its input argument. Execution can get past the `logits_pred = enumeration_tuple[1]` line, as evidenced by a print statement printing a simple string, but it halts whenever I `print(logits_pred)`. So apparently, whenever I actually need the passed value, the process stops. I do not get an exception or error message. When using either Python's built-in `map()` function or a for-loop, the function finishes succesfully. I should have sufficient memory en computing power available. All processes are writing to different files. `enumerate(predictions)` yields correct index-value pairs, as expected. I call this function using `Pool.map()`:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
file_results = pool.map(evaluate_prediction, enumerate(predictions))
```

Why is it hanging? And how can I get an exception, so I know what's going wrong?

UPDATE: After outsourcing the mapped function to another module, importing it from there, and adding `__init__.py` to my directory, I manage to print the first item in the tuple, but not the second.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before, and a solution that worked for me was to put the function you want to parallelize in  a separate module and then import it.

```
from eval_prediction import evaluate_prediction
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
file_results = pool.map(evaluate_prediction, enumerate(predictions))
```

I assume you will save the function definition inside a filename eval_prediction.py in same directory. Make sure you have __init__.py as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am getting a little further now; I can print the first item in the tuple, but it now hangs at the second (`print(enumeration_tuple[1])`).